# Acceder a una variable declarada en una clase en PHP

Tags: php

tengo una duda simple sobre PHP. Tengo el siguiente código en un archivo llamado gato.php:

```
class Animal{
    public $foodLevel=5;
}
class Cat extends Animal{
}
```

Luego tengo otro archivo en el cual tengo:

```
include_once "gato.php";
$susi = new Cat();
echo $susi->$foodLevel;
```

Y obtengo los siguientes errores:

> Undefined variable: foodLevel
>
> Cannot access empty property

¿Cómo podría acceder a la variable foodLevel desde el segundo archivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás intentando acceder la propiedad como si su nombre estuviera almacenado en una variable, la forma que buscas es:

```
echo  $susi->foodLevel;
```

---

Lo que intentas hacer funcionaría si fuera algo así:

```
$myVar = 'foodLevel';

echo $susi->$myVar;
```

Comment: Es verdad, muchas gracias por la respuesta!